# How to have internet connection over VPN while "Microsoft Firewall Client for ISA server" is running?

Tags: vpn, firewall, internet, connection, isa-server

I have the software mentioned in the title running on my machine.
When I connect over VPN to my company's network, my internet connection gets borked, because somehow the ISA firewall blocks it. This is completely idiotic, because my work involves extensive use of the internet, so having to disconnect and reconnect continuously seriously cripples my productivity. (Meaning: I'm tearing my hair out here.)

Can I have my VPN connection and somehow still have my internet connection too? I'm open to any solution.

Comment: To those voting to close, Not sure why VPN access and ISA configuration would belong on SuperUser?

Comment: My guess is because it's an end-user question?

Answer (score 1):

It's called split tunneling and is usually a configuration option for the provider of the VPN, centrally managed. Enabling it is a serious security concern and it's usually disabled just like you've noticed.

However, you should be able to gain internet access anyway - though through the work internet connection via the VPN instead (might be slower). If that doesn't work either, I'd say something is either misconfigured or left like that on purpose.

So ask your VPN administrator. Or your boss - if you need it to work, they should fix it.

Changing the configuration yourself, if at all possible, could (often is) a violation of user policy and could have serious security and legal implications.

Trouble is, the ISA firewall client as far as I recall is "only" used to supplement authentication and add logging information from the inside - not act as a VPN client? That's usually built into the operating system. But perhaps that's changed or I'm misinformed...

Answer (score 0):

this isn't the simplest of answers, but I have the same requirement of being able to access the internet using my home connection while using VPN to my work.

I ended up using VirtualBox to run a virual machine...inside the virtual machine I have the VPN client installed (cisco in my case) and connect like that...I then use Remote Desktop or whatever inside the Virtual Machine against Work's network.
The host (running VirtualBox) can then access the regular internet no problems while the virtual machine cannot (as the VPN has taken over)...hope that makes sense...

I'm pretty sure there are other ways, but this is fairly straightforward. As a virtual machine operating system, I just use Windows 2000 as all the software will run on it (e.g. the VPN client) and it requires very little resources (RAM, Hd) so then VirtualBox requires less resources of the host.